# Pycharm - Pyramid Mac OS X Freezing on Run

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

Running Python 3.4.3, PyCharm Pro 4.5, and using VirtualEnviroment created within PyCharm.

Initialally after building a starter scaffold and running the project, it 
"runs" with errors, but then using Tools->Run setup.py tasks...(Develop)...(OK)...Running again causes the application to freeze with no other results.

Any suggestions? I can't seem to find anyone else running into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently setting or adding

```
pyramid.includes = pyramid_debugtoolbar
```

currently causes pycharm / pyramid to crash / lockup Pycharm. Removing this allows the application to run normally.